# AWS Amplify ignoring query string

Tags: reactjs, query-string, aws-amplify

I am running a React app on AWS amplify and when the password link (with query string) is clicked from the email in the format of `https://www.domain.co.uk/resetPassword?email=a@example.com&token=5p0-2ce1c23665f782e62cw69`

it is just returned back to the homepage. I suspect it is something to do with the second rule. If I access this directly into the URL browser, it works: `https://www.domain.co.uk/resetPassword?email=a@example.com&token=5p0-2ce1c23665f782e62cw69`

```
[
    {
        "source": "https://domain.co.uk",
        "target": "https://www.domain.co.uk",
        "status": "302",
        "condition": null
    },

    {
        "source": "/<*>",
        "target": "/index.html",
        "status": "404-200",
        "condition": null
    },
    {
        "source": "</^[^.]+$|\\.(?!(css|gif|ico|jpg|js|png|txt|svg|woff|ttf|map|json)$)([^.]+$)/>",
        "target": "/index.html",
        "status": "200",
        "condition": null
    }
]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

i have same problem here and i solve after read this [post](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-hosting/issues/97). Add www to your domain, example:

```
https://yourdomain.com

to

https://www.yourdomain.com
```

Thanks to user https://github.com/DevPowers

Comment: this was my problem, saved my life today!